# positional indexers are out-of-bounds how to fix it

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning

i tried to iterate my dataframe df2 taht contains the informations bellow

```
      N_Ordre       PSN       DATE_DE_DEPART         fin_interval
0           1  A4BA0D07  2022-01-01T00:00:00  2022-01-01T23:59:59
1           2  A4BA0D07  2022-01-01T00:00:00  2022-01-01T23:59:59
2           3  04BB0607  2022-01-01T00:00:00  2022-01-01T23:59:59
3           4  85BA0BCF  2022-01-02T00:00:00  2022-01-02T23:59:59
4           5  85BA0BF4  2022-01-02T00:00:00  2022-01-02T23:59:59
...       ...       ...                  ...                  ...
1593     1638  00BA06C9  2022-04-17T00:00:00  2022-04-17T23:59:59
1594     1639  A4BA0E48  2022-04-17T00:00:00  2022-04-17T23:59:59
1595     1640  A4BA0D33  2022-04-17T00:00:00  2022-04-17T23:59:59
1596     1641  A4BA0CF9  2022-04-17T00:00:00  2022-04-17T23:59:59
1597     1642  85BA0BF9  2022-04-17T00:00:00  2022-04-17T23:59:59
```

with the sample code bellow:

```
for i,row in df2.iterrows():
    url = "https://aaa.com/mw/psn/"+row['PSN']+"/record/16?key=nLsBvp0YedcXUcaU73fs&from_date="+row['DATE_DE_DEPART']+"&to_date="+row['fin_interval']
    print("search by psn")
#     print(url)
    
    response = requests.get(url)
    response_json = response.json()
    dictionary = json.dumps(response.json(), sort_keys = True, indent = 4)
    #print(dictionary)


    df33 = pd.read_json(dictionary)
    df3 = df33.iloc[: , [25,0,11,12,22,1]].copy()
    print('--------------------------------------------------------------')
    
    print('data frame 3 containt only needed row',i)
```

i tried to ignore the line that causes this error but it appeared more than one time in multiple lines

```
IndexError: positional indexers are out-of-bounds
```

so how can i fix it

Comment: have you tried printing `df33`? does it have 26 columns or more?

Comment: @Tranbi no it has less than 26

Comment: So that's your problem right there... Did you intend to select *rows* instead? Then it should be `df33.iloc[[25,0,11,12,22,1], :]`

Comment: @Tranbi it still apears the same error

Comment: Does df33 have more than 26 rows? :-P is it the line raising the error? (Your question is not clear about that)

Comment: @Tranbi The df33 hase less than 26s but more than 26 rows